# ListPopupWindow - Orientation change

Tags: android, popupwindow

Okay so I have a simple ListPopupWindow assigned with String[] and in portrait works great.

If I open the List and then change the orinentation it messes everything up.

When I show the Popup for first time in portrait:

[image: 1]

When I change orientation while the Popup is opened:

[image: 2]

When I open it while in landscape mode:

[image: 3]

I want while is opened and I change orientation to go to the button view, and when I open it in landscape mode to be wrapped because if I want to choose about or help and feedback I am not able because its not scrollable. How can I achieve that?